# Limit, offset with joins and full text search indexes in MySQl

Tags: sql, mysql, join

I have 3 tables

1. users

```
uid | type_name | etc ...                           
----+-----------+--------
```

2. addresses

```
user_id | address | name | latitude | etc...                           
--------+---------+------+----------+-------
```

3. working_hours

```
agent_id | day_of_week | opens_at |  etc...                           
--------+-------------+----------+--------
```

**Addresses** has a full text search index on *name* and *address*. I have a query to join all of the tables like so:

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.address, a.name, a.latitude,
       a.longitude, u.phone_number, u.type_name, u.uid,
       closes_at, opens_at, day_of_week
FROM addresses a
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u on u.uid = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN working_hours wh on u.uid = wh.agent_id
WHERE (MATCH (name, address) AGAINST ('+some street* +some name*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) );
```

It works fine, but I also need to **add LIMIT and OFFSET features**. If I redo line 4 as a subquery like:

```sql
FROM (SELECT * from addresses LIMIT x OFFSET x) a
```

it won't work cause it creates a sub tables dynamically, and there is no index for it.

if we add limit and offset to the end of the query it would limit overall results.
How can I reqrite a query so that it won't limit join results and apply it to addresses table results?

Comment: See [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) #5 and #3

Comment: Instead of using a subquery, save the results of that subquery in a temporary table. Then add a FT index to the table.

Comment: Do you really want to receive addresses where no-one resides?

Comment: @Barmar Seems like the only way to do it, but then the temp table will have to be manually cleaned up before every use.

Comment: Temporary tables go away automatically when the session ends.

Answer (score 0):

use folowing Code:

```
 SET @limit = 10;
SET @offset = 0;

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      a.id,
      a.address,
      a.name,
      a.latitude,
      a.longitude,
      u.phone_number,
      u.type_name,  
      u.uid,
      wh.closes_at,
      wh.opens_at,
      wh.day_of_week
    FROM 
      addresses a
      LEFT JOIN users u 
        ON u.uid = a.user_id
      LEFT JOIN working_hours wh 
        ON u.uid = wh.agent_id
    WHERE
      MATCH(a.name, a.address) AGAINST('+some street* +some name*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY
      a.id
 ) temp
LIMIT 
  @limit
OFFSET
  @offset;
```